# How to know when PDF was edited?

Tags: windows, pdf

I will have an online exam where I download a PDF, fill it out and upload it again. We are given 20 additional minutes to upload the document, but we are not allowed to edit it further during the upload time. Is there any way for them to see when I saved the document on my desktop and when I stopped editing? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

PDF allows JavaScript to run within it during validation of field entry and modification.

There is a lot of scope for them to monitor any number of things, there is no way to know what is happening without painstakingly analysing the PDF file with a PDF tool such as Adobe Acrobat. Acrobat Reader is not enough.